# Putting a condition in a for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

Let's say

```
i = 1:2029  
j = c(3,6,3,5,123,323,423,652,743,885,932)
```

for loop generally looks like

```
for (x in i) {  }
```

in here, I would like to calculate the function for x that are not same as j
so it would be something like

```
for (x in i & !j) {  }
```

but obviously, this kind of command doesn't work.
Is there are command that expresses my intention?

Comment: Not sure what you want exaclty with the `& !j`, but this might be the answer: `for (x in i) { if (x != j) {}}`

Comment: i in j is i%in%j

Comment: You need `for x in setdiff(i, j)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
for (x in i[-which(i %in% j)]) {   }
```